# how to extract the column name and data type from nested struct type in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to extract the column name and data type from nested struct type in spark

schema getting like this:

```
(events,StructType(
   StructField(beaconType,StringType,true),     
   StructField(beaconVersion,StringType,true), 
   StructField(client,StringType,true), 
   StructField(data,StructType(
      StructField(ad,StructType(
         StructField(adId,StringType,true)
      )
   )
)
```

I want to convert into below format

```
Array[(String, String)] = Array(
  (client,StringType), 
  (beaconType,StringType), 
  (beaconVersion,StringType), 
  (phase,StringType)
```

could you please help on this

Comment: where is `phase` coming from? It doesn't appear in the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question is somewhat unclear, but if you're looking for a way to "flatten" a DataFrame schema (i.e. get an array of all non-struct fields), here's one:

```
def flatten(schema: StructType): Array[StructField] = schema.fields.flatMap { f =>
  f.dataType match {
    case struct: StructType => flatten(struct)
    case _ => Array(f)
  }
}
```

For example:

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("events", 
  StructType(Seq(
    StructField("beaconVersion", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("client", StringType, true),
    StructField("data", StructType(Seq(
      StructField("ad", StructType(Seq(
        StructField("adId", StringType, true)
      )))
    )))
  )))
))

println(flatten(schema).toList)
// List(StructField(beaconVersion,IntegerType,true), StructField(client,StringType,true), StructField(adId,StringType,true))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dataframe with a `StructType` column i.e.:

```
df.printSchema() 
// root
// |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
// |    |-- embedded_data: string (nullable = true)
```

You can extract the subfield `embedded_data` of the `StructType` column `data` as follows:

```
df.select("data.embedded_data").printSchema()
// root
// |-- data.embedded_data: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have df1 and df2 as two dataFrames, and you want to compare the fields,

```
df1.schema.foreach(schema_1=>{ 
  df2.schema.foreach(schema_2=>{ 
  // **to Compare The names**
  if(schema_1.name.equals(schema_2.name)){ // to Compare The names
          // **comparing the data Type**
           print(schema_1.dataType.equals(schema_2.dataType))

  }
}) 
})
```