# Accessing a json array nested in a structure using Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I wish to access different fields / subfields from a fairly deeply nested structure with arrays in order to do arithmetic operations on them. Some of the data is actually in the field names themselves (the structure that I have to access is created that way and there is nothing I can do about that). In particular, I have a list of numbers as the field names which I must use, and these will change from one json file to the next, so I must dynamically infer what those field names are and then use them with subfield values.

I've looked at this: [Access names of fields in struct Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44214945/access-names-of-fields-in-struct-spark-sql)
Unfortunately, I do not know what will be the field names for my structure so I cannot use this.

I've also tried this, which looked promising: [how to extract the column name and data type from nested struct type in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42129111/how-to-extract-the-column-name-and-data-type-from-nested-struct-type-in-spark)
Unfortunately, whatever the magic in the "flatten" function does, I have not been able to adapt it to fieldnames rather than fields themselves.

Here is an example json dataset. It represents consumption baskets:

- each of the two baskets "comp A" and "comp B" have a number of prices as subfields: compA.'55.80' is a price, compA.'132.88' is another pice, etc.
- I wish to associate those unit prices to the quantity available in their respective subfields: compA.'55.80'.comment[0].qty (500), as well as compA.'55.80'.comment[0].qty (600), should both be associated to 55.80. compA.'132.88'.comment[0].qty (700) should be associated to 132.88. etc.

```
{"type":"test","name":"john doe","products":{
    "baskets":{
        "comp A":{
            "55.80":[{"type":"fun","comment":{"qty":500,"text":"hello"}},{"type":"work","comment":{"qty":600,"text":"hello"}}]
            ,"132.88":[{"type":"fun","comment":{"qty":700,"text":"hello"}}]
            ,"0.03":[{"type":"fun","comment":{"qty":500,"text":"hello"}},{"type":"work","comment":{"qty":600,"text":"hello"}}]
        }
        ,"comp B":{
            "55.70":[{"type":"fun","comment":{"qty":500,"text":"hello"}},{"type":"work","comment":{"qty":600,"text":"hello"}}]
            ,"132.98":[{"type":"fun","comment":{"qty":300,"text":"hello"}},{"type":"work","comment":{"qty":900,"text":"hello"}}]
            ,"0.01":[{"type":"fun","comment":{"qty":400,"text":"hello"}}]
        }
    }
}}
```

I would like to obtain all these numbers in a dataframe in order to do some operations on them:

```
+ -------+---------+----------+
+ basket | price   | quantity +
+ -------+---------+----------+
+ comp A | 55.80   | 500      +
+ comp A | 55.80   | 600      +
+ comp A | 132.88  | 700      +
+ comp A | 0.03    | 500      +
+ comp A | 0.03    | 600      +
+ comp B | 55.70   | 500      +
+ comp B | 55.70   | 600      +
+ comp B | 132.98  | 300      +
+ comp B | 132.98  | 900      +
+ comp B | 0.01    | 400      +
+ -------+---------+----------+
```

The original dataset is accessed as such:

```
scala> myDs
res135: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [products: struct<baskets: struct<compA: struct<55.80: array<struct .....
```

Comment: I'm making a bit of progress using the following: spark.read.json(myDs.withColumn("compA",get_json_object($"json","$.products.baskets.compA")).select("compA").rdd.map(_.getString(0))).columns
This yields: Array[String] = Array(55.80, 132.88, 0.03, ....
This is not enough, but it's a start...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525013/how-to-query-nested-json-with-internal-arrays-in-spark-on-basis-of-equality-chec/52534617#52534617  this should give you some guidance. exploding reqd.

Comment: Any joy yet on this front?

Comment: The main difficulties are the fact that 1. I do not know the schema in advance since the prices change and 2. The fact that the prices are field names. Unless I am mistaken, the example using you linked to with films does therefore not help in this respect?

Comment: That example I had is pretty straight forward. U need to know something on schema.

Comment: I do know a lot about the schema: products.baskets.compA contains a list of unkown fields, all of which have prices in their fieldnames. Then, under each of those fields is an array. I have tried the fieldnames function by tweaking the second link provided in description, which is a good start for dynamic schemas...

Comment: I do not have much to show for my work, the best I was able to get is that Array of prices from my 1st comment, but I am still unable to figure out a way to access the subfields from that array :(

Comment: Some of the data is actually in the field names themselves (the structure that I have to access is created that way and there is nothing I can do about that).

Comment: That is indeed a first from what I can see, not sure what to make of this.

Comment: I've got a few clues I think, but I cannot solve this. You can infer nothing based on variables in field naming. I suggest the format be changed. Interested to see who can solve. Success.

Answer (score 1):

This approach of processing data that comes in as a column name is not an approach to follow. It will simply not work.

Comment: i haven't completely given up yet (as I have no power over the data format, and the data is there...). i'll post updates as they come along.

Comment: Good for you but real hard yakka.

Comment: this answer states that it's impossible but does not show why it is impossible. Actually, I am pretty sure this is possible => I'd prefer that someone (maybe me) find the actual answer and post it here to document / help others.

Comment: Then I look forward to the answer one day. I note that there are more than a few experts on this platform, far better than me, and no response to-date.

Comment: Solved yet? Pls post if so.

Comment: How r things progresing?